Joomla 5 - Custom User Profile Plugin with SQL Field: How to display value_field on Profile Page
I needed a set of custom user fields that writes into a custom table. I copied the default User-Profile plugin in Joomla v5.1.2 and made the necessary code changes to create my custom plugin profile6. The plugin and all the fields are working as needed with the exception of the SQL Form Field.
In the profile-edit view, it correctly displays the drop-down list from the value_field column.
However, in the profile view, it displays the key_field value of the user. I would like it to display the value_field.
I have scoured the Internet and tried countless coding suggestions to find a solution, bu to no avail. Interestingly, when I add a custom SQL field (accessed by going to Users -> Fields), it correctly displays the value_field in both profile and profile-edit views. From my understanding, all custom-fields created this way use the fields plugin. I cannot use it as it accesses and writes to the _fields_values table. The SQL Form Field that I created uses /libraries/src/Form/Field/SqlField.php.

Purpose and code details
Purpose: Store the user's state (geographic location in the US) using the two-letter state abbreviation, but display the full name of the state in Profile View, and a drop-down of all state names in the Profile-Edit View.
Code Details
The field definition in profile6.xml:
<field
    name="memstate"
    type="sql"
    label="PLG_USER_PROFILE6_FIELD_STATE_LABEL"
    description="PLG_USER_PROFILE6_FIELD_STATE_DESCRIPTION"
    layout="joomla.form.field.list"
    query="SELECT abbr, memstate FROM #__list_of_states"
    key_field="abbr"
    value_field="memstate"
    header="PLG_USER_PROFILE6_FIELD_STATE_HEADER"
/>

The SQL Query accesses the two-column table _list_of_states (which has 53 rows). Here are a few rows of that table:

Here are sections of the code in Profile6.php.
Inside onContentPrepareData
if (\is_object($data)) {
    $userId = $data->id ?? 0;

    if (!isset($data->profile6) && $userId > 0) {
        // Load the profile6 data from the database.
        $db    = $this->getDatabase();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select(
                [
                    $db->quoteName('address1'),
                    $db->quoteName('city'),
                    $db->quoteName('memstate'),
                    $db->quoteName('zipcode'),
                    $db->quoteName('phone'),
                    $db->quoteName('phone_type'),
                    $db->quoteName('birthdate'),
                ]
            )
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__user_memprofiles'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = :userid')
            ->bind(':userid', $userId);

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadAssoc();

        // Merge the profile data.
        $data->profile6 = [];

        $data->profile6['address1'] = $results['address1'];
        $data->profile6['city'] = $results['city'];
        $data->profile6['memstate'] = $results['memstate'];
        $data->profile6['zipcode'] = $results['zipcode'];
        $data->profile6['phone'] = $results['phone'];
        $data->profile6['phone_type'] = $results['phone_type'];
        $data->profile6['birthdate'] = $results['birthdate'];
    }
}

Would really appreciate help in fixing the issue.

After further investigation, I found out that the code run on the Plugin event onContentPrepareData is the section that needs to be modified to solve my issue. So, I removed other sections of the code I had originally posted.

I am a little disappointed in the lack of any response by the forum members. With help, I was able to solve the issue and am posting it for anyone who might face this issue.
The user data pulled from the database contains the two-letter state abbreviation. Hence, this data has to be modified (replaced with the full name of the state) when onContentPrepareData is run - a Plugin Event allowing you to modify pre-fill data of a form.
The solution consists of two steps:

Create a custom public static function which contains the code to modify the value.

Apply #1 to modify the HTML output by applying the class to the fieldname of the field you are modifying.


STEP ONE
The default User-Profile plugin modifies the Date of Birth field using a public static function. I followed with a similar approach by adding public static function memstate($value). The initial value is the two state abbreviation. The static function looks up the full name of the state and returns the new value.  Here's the code that is added within onContentPrepareData.
/**
 * Returns value_field value by looking up key_field value.
 *
 * @param   string  $value  value to use
 *
 * @return  mixed
 */
public static function memstate($value)
{
    $abbr = $value;

    if ($value == '') {
        return;
    }

    $db    = Factory::getDbo();
    $value = (array) $value;
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query
        ->select($db->quoteName('memstate').' AS text, abbr AS value')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__list_of_states'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('abbr') . ' = :abbr')
        ->bind(':abbr', $abbr, ParameterType::STRING);


    $db->setQuery($query);
    $items = $db->loadObjectList();

    $texts = [];

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (in_array($item->value, $value)) {
            $texts[] = $item->text;
        }
    }

    return htmlentities(implode(', ', $texts));

}

STEP TWO
You register the class using Joomla's HTMLHelper. I followed the code used in the default User-Profile plugin, which consists of checking to see if the class is registered by any other plugin, and if not, register the class for your field.
You need to register the class inside the IF statement that loads the data from the database (which is within the onContentPrepareData section of the code).
Here's my code:
    if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.memstate')) {
        HTMLHelper::register('users.memstate', [__CLASS__, 'memstate']);
    }

Caution: In both my case and the ones used by the default User-Profile plugin, the name of the class (as defined in the public static function) and the fieldname are the same (memstate in my case).
You can have a modifying class that can be applied to multiple fields. In such cases, the class name and fieldname will be different. The generic code is:
    if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.<your field name>')) {
        HTMLHelper::register('users.<your field name>', [__CLASS__, '<your class name (public static function)>']);
    }


Don't forget to Accept your own answer and get some more reputation points and lets people searching the future that this post has a valid solution.

Thanks! @Irata  Will do.
